# Wierd result using REGEXP_REPLACE - strings are aggregated

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace some letters with others.

This is my query - I'll be using `sakila` sample db:

```
SELECT first_name,
       CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name,'a','d') USING utf16) AS replaced
FROM sakila.actor
```

And this is the result (MySql Workbench, 8.0.11) - As you can see, results are "aggregated":

[image]

I tried reproducing it with [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5suLeHJtjMEp7mweXQ6TmS/0), but it doesn't reproduce.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WHY use utf16??
- Why use `REGEXP_REPLACE` when `REPLACE` does the job?  (Switching *may* resolve the problem.)
- There is a bug in certain versions that is probably causing the ever-lengthening results.  See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803 , which was fixed in 8.0.12.  Upgrade.
- It does not matter what version of Workbench you are using; what version of MySQL are you using.

Comment: Well, my snippet is just a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable snippet of my original code, which queries Hebrew letters (hence utf16) to remove diacritics using a certain pattern (hence `REGEX_REPLACE`). Installed MySQL version is the same: 8.0.11. Upgrading solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: Some reason not to use the ubiquitous utf8 instead of very-rarely-used utf16?

Comment: No. Will change.

Comment: Assuming you already have data in the table, you probably need the `CONVERT TO` variant of `ALTER`.